# How to filter into an Object (js) looking only into desired properties

Tags: javascript, excel

I'm Using SheetJS (https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs) to use information from an excel table. What I got till now is an object with the cell names as objects, so like this:

```
Sheet1 = {
  A1: {
    t: "s",
    v: "Jhon"
  },
  A2: {
    t: "s",
    v: "Doe"
  }
}
```

and so on.
And now I need to find the number I want (depending on the day) only looking between cells B14 to AF14) and return the seven cells bellow the cell I got on the previous step.
The hardest part for me is to look only at the objects B14, C14.. AF14.

Comment: Please provide some example input and output.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure that **sheetjs** gives an ability to retrieve certain cells instead of whole grid, but I never used it.

What I would do:

```
const sheet = {
  A1: {
    t: "s",
    v: "Jhon"
  },
  A2: {
    t: "s",
    v: "Doe"
  }
}

const start = 'B'.charCodeAt(0)
const end = 'F'.charCodeAt(0)

const objs = {}

for (let i = start; i <= end; i += 1) {
  const key = String.fromCharCode(i) + '14'
  if (key in sheet) {
    objs[key] = sheet[key]
  }
}
```

This code should return an object of objects representing cells between B14 and F14.

You can do this too:

```
const sheet = {
  A1: {
    t: "s",
    v: "Jhon"
  },
  A2: {
    t: "s",
    v: "Doe"
  }
}

const array = Object.entries(sheet).filter(([key]) => key.match(/^[B-F]14$/))
```

This will give you array of filtered objects.

If you want the 7 cells under that just make a second loop.